# How do I convert an integer to its 32 Bit Binary equivalent

Tags: c

I am trying to flip bits of the binary that is set bits will be unset and vice-versa. For that matter I need to first know how to convert an integer value to 32 bit binary .

Comment: possible duplicate of [C Programming - Convert an integer to binary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190685/c-programming-convert-an-integer-to-binary)

Comment: `int x = 42; x = !x`?

Comment: `~` is the negation operator in C.

Comment: If it's stored in an `int`, it's already binary.

Comment: @DanielKleinstein: `-` is the negation operator. `~` is the bitwise complement operator.

Comment: What do you mean by "binary"? The int is already binary (somewhere). Do you want to convert it to a string?

Comment: This has me scratching my head a little.  You realize integers are already stored as binary, right?

Comment: How is this related to functional programming? And are you assuming an`int` is 32 bits?

Comment: @CodieCodeMonkey I just mean to output that 32 bits only .. i.e for 1 the output be 00000000000000000000000000000001. Hope thats good??

Comment: @KeithThompson An alternative term for bitwise complement is bitwise negation.. Really just a matter of semantics. The standard actually refers to `!` as the (logical) negation operator.

Comment: So you want the output of your program to be a sequence of 32 ASCII characters, `'0'` and `'1'`? That's not at all clear from your question -- and that's not what "32-bit binary" means.

Comment: if what you want is to output binary string representation, i think there is no such function, hex and oct are feasible though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the left-shift operator:

```
/* A 1 in the left-most bit, 0's everywhere else */
#define MASK 0x80000000
...
for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    printf(num & MASK ? "1" : "0");
    num << 1;
}
```

Of course you should consider that on different machines, integers may not be 32 bits.

At each iteration, you test if there's a 1 in the left-most bit by doing a binary and with `MASK`.  If the result is non-zero, you print a 1, otherwise a 0.

Answer (score -1):

There is no direct function to do that i guess. You can work on the binary of an int with Bitwise operators, but to get a Binary representation in an array you need to write your own function. It will be pretty simple though.

Comment: The OP didn't say anything about an array.

Comment: I meant, you can use '>>' and '&' and other Bitwise operators to do Binary operation on the binary version of the int. but if you want to sat print the binary version of say 15 which is 1111, you have to write a code which will do this for you.

Comment: And how does that involve arrays?

Comment: How else can u store a series of 1's and 0's?

Comment: go ahead store 10001010100100010101000101000010001000100000111111111111100011010000010010 in an integer in C! If u really want to do this then go for BigInteger in Java or go for Python

Comment: What's your point? That's 74 bits, which will easily fit in an `__int128`, which gcc supports on some but not all platforms. But the OP is clearly starting with an integer value, whose bits will obviously fit in an integer. Bottom line: the question is too vague to be answered meaningfully.

Comment: oh yeah, __int128 will do it. I totally forgot about that. I just had normal int in my mind which will prevent you to do this.

Comment: `__int128` isn't relevant to the OP's question anyway.